# Help with Apache Tomcat SSL Certificate - Says self-signed even though the certificate was purchased from a CA

Tags: ssl, tomcat

I recently purchased an SSL certificate from a CA for an Apache Tomcat Server using Bitnami and Liferay. I have configured the tomcat server.xml file as follows:

```
<Connector
    port="8443"
    maxThreads="200" scheme="https"
    secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
    keystoreFile="/opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat/conf/ssl/tomcat.keystore"
    keystorePass="mypass"
    clientAuth="false"
    sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

And according to my CA, I have added the certificate and its intermediates to the keystore correctly, but when I run the domain through any SSL checker, it still says the certificate is self-signed, and that the name on the certificate is "www.example.com". Any advice on getting the CA certificate working?

Comment: Have you imported the certificate they provided and the private key you generated before you made the CSR into the keystore?

Comment: List the keys/certs using `keytool`

Comment: You're running on a non-default port. SSL Labs will only scan port 443. Try from an external host yourself with [testssl.sh](https://testssl.sh/) on both ports. Does this still give the same results?